# How to answer a comment requesting unknown further information

Tags: support, comments, answers

What should I do when, after posting an answer, I'm asked in a comment for further clarifications and/or a different solution (but still in-topic) and I don't know anything more?

Should I answer that I don't know or should I just leave it at that? The etiquette in this site is different from that which usually applies in forums...

Comment: Does the answer in question still, in your opinion, answer the question as originally posed?

Comment: @JosephWright: I posted it because I thought so, but actually I gave only a partial answer. [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156041/3d-projection-of-a-text-with-tikz/156043#156043) is the post I'm talking about. (Sorry, I made a mess with past comments, I didn't want to be a bother.)

Comment: Use `comments` to get the `unknown` further information. Comments are meant for further followup and clarification or even invite the User(If willing) to the [Chatroom](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3591/15717) to avoid long comment history.

Comment: @texenthusiast: the problem is that I posted an answer, but I don't know how to answer the question asked in a comment of my answer.

Comment: Option 1. Mention what's missing in your answer as note and improve later, It's no sin to say `I don't know, I know this much, but I will improve(If you wish so)`. Option 2. If you don't feel good, delete the answer and Post an answer once you find it that matches OP requirements.

Comment: In addition to @texenthusiast 's nice classification, the options are not equally weighted. Delete the answer only if you are really sure that it can't fly for anybody. Often I gather fragments from partial answers in a few questions for my final fix/solution. Besides, just say, `I can't see right away how but I'll come back to this` and please come back if you find a way :)